# Software center not working on kali linux?

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux

I followed the instructions for installing kali linux and put these commands into the terminal:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install software-center
```

I also added:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/ /kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/ /wheezy main contrib non-free
```

to my sources list. When I start up the software center a tab appears in the tool bar menu titled "starting software center" a seconds later it just closes. No window comes up or anything the tab just closes. This appears in terminal when I type sudo software-center:

root@MattJones:~# sudo software-center
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 131, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 49, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 27, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.backend.channel import is_channel_available
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/channel.py", line 25, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.distro import get_distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 179, in <module>
    distro_instance=_get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 162, in _get_distro
    module =  __import__(distro_id, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
ImportError: No module named Kali
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: is it because your sources list for kali has a leading forward-slash in front of "kali" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. open the terminal
2. type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. type `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
4. paste the repository lines that you had mentioned in your question along with the following lines on that terminal:

   ```
   deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
   deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
   ```
5. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
7. type `sudo apt-get install software-center`

you can also install synaptic which is the package manager of Debian kali Linux . It is also like a software center

```
apt-get install synaptic
```

I think the problem did arize because may be have not upgraded your kali (only updated)

Comment: Welcome to U&L. I edited your post to confirm to the formatting we use here. There is far less need for HTML tags then you used in your original answer (have a look at the edit history for comparison).

Answer (score 0):

found a solution :

1. `gedit /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py`
2. Go to line 159
3. Change `lsb_info["ID"]` to `"Debian"`
   Before: distro_id = lsb_info["ID"]
   After: distro_id = "Debian"
4. Type in terminal: `update-software-center`
5. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case some one is still struggling to find solution for this
Following command worked for me.

The Idea is to clean the catalog cache of the gnome-softwares
For me it was at `~/.cache/gnome-software`
So just running following command worked for me

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/gnome-software
```

How did I find the folder?
I simply ran following command to find all caching related folders

```
ls -R / | grep cache
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be in your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://kali.download/kali/ kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Then:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install software-center
```

And:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think that Debian entry should be there

Comment: What does that picture show?

Comment: @roaima As we all see, that picture shows a fully functional software-center on  kali and the version of it.